# Find the most recent two payments per customer then find the difference between the two

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have the following dataframe. I would like to find the most recent two payments for each ID and find the difference between the two payments then take an average. For example, I'd like to take calculate the following amounts (2018-2017/2018) and put the output in a new column. I'm a python beginner and I'm not certain how to do this.

I tried:

```
df["Growthrate"] = df.loc[:, "2016":].apply(lambda x: (v := x[x > 0][-2:]).diff()[-1] / v[-1], axis=1)
```

but I keep getting an invalid syntax error.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I'm stuck.

```
ID       2016   2017   2018   2019       
25471    50     0      10     400
22547    0      50     25     0
38754    0      1000   0      50
14523    100    500    0     1000
14789    400    400    400    400
```

The output should be

```
ID       2016   2017   2018   2019  Growth     
25471    50     0      10     400    97.5%
22547    0      50     25     0      -100%
38754    0      1000   0      50     -1900%
14523    100    500    0     1000     100%
14789    400    400    400    400     0%
```

Comment: When you have an error, here a SyntaxError, and you tell us about, please share it ;) [edit] your post to add it

Comment: I've just copied your code, the IDE seems ok with the code, no syntaxerror

Answer (score 1):

It may be owing to the *“the walrus operator”* `:=` that was [introduced quite recently in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) that your current version of Python is not supporting.

If you are using Python version lower than version 3.8, you should probably either upgrade it (if you can) or rewrite the statement without using `v` and `:=`,  like below:

```
df["Growthrate"] = df.loc[:, "2016":].apply(lambda x: (x[x > 0][-2:]).diff()[-1] / x[x > 0][-2:][-1], axis=1) 


# Output

      ID  2016  2017  2018  2019  Growthrate
0  25471    50     0    10   400       0.975
1  22547     0    50    25     0      -1.000
2  38754     0  1000     0    50     -19.000
3  14523   100   500     0  1000       0.500
4  14789   400   400   400   400       0.000
```

You may still need a little bit formatting on the new column to convert decimal values to percentages.

Comment: IndexError: index out of bounds                                                                                
      KeyError: -1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
----> df["Growthrate"] = df.loc[:,"2016":].apply(lambda x:(x[x > 0][-2:]).diff()[-1]/x[x > 0][-2:][-1], axis=1)

Comment: @KBar  That's both good news and bad news!   Good news that you have get rid of Syntax Error already and get into running the code.  Just want to double confirm what Python and Pandas versions you have ?

Comment: @KBar  You can see that I just extracted your code `(v := x[x > 0][-2:])` by removing the `v :=` part and replacing the reference to `v` by the code that it was assigned to, ie.  `x[x > 0][-2:]` in the code above.  I also tested it ok with your sample data.  So, either your actual data just not what's shown in the sample data or another error embedded in your code.  You may need to further look at that.

Comment: I'm using 3.7.6. I saw your recommendation —thank you. I'm worried about code deprecation.

Comment: @KBar  Try upgrading your Python version if you can.  You will be able to use your original code and might also come without the IndexError with new version if your data is really those showed in the sample.

Comment: i upgraded but now getting an out of bounds error

Comment: @KBar  which Python version you upgrade to ?   And what version of Pandas you are using too ?

Comment: 3.8.3 and pandas 1.2.4

Comment: @KBar  Those versions are quite recent and should support the original code you use.  I also use similar versions.  You still got problem with your code ?  What's the error now ?